# Setting sampling frequency for adc in arm cortex m3

Tags: arm, microcontroller, cortex-m

I am a beginner in the field of microcontroller programming and currently i am working with an arm cortex m3 mcu. I want to program the adc to read voltages at 1khz. The clock of MCU runs at 16Mhz. I am confused as to which of the following two methods i must adopt:

1. use a delay routine
2. put mcu to sleep using wfi instruction so that adc samples at 1khz

Can anyone please tell me an optimum solution for this? If wfi is used, how can the subroutine be written??

Answer (score 0):

There is no one method you "must" adopt. There are different options depending on a particular implementation.

Using a delay routine isn't the best way because you're tying up the micro while waiting for the next sample to be initiated. If you want to keep the micro doing other things while waiting for the next sample to come though, the best way to do this is to set up a timer to go off every millisecond. In the timer interrupt routine you can then either initiate the ADC or, better, set a flag that the infinite loop sees and sets of the next ADC read.

You could send the micro to sleep and wake it every millisecond, but do you really want an STM32 doing nothing but taking a sample 1000 times a second?

Are you not having the PLL step up the clock from 16MHz to a higher frequency BTW?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the solution here would be to used a General Purpose Counter/Timer to trigger ADC conversions. Things you need to figure out:

- How to enable global interrupts
- How to enable timer interrupt
- How to calculate timer parameters so that the [ISR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler) triggers, e.g. every 1 ms (1 kHz)
- Either use software triggering of ADC conversion in ISR or even better to internally send the conversion signal from the timer directly to the ADC.
- Eventually use DMA to transfer your data from ADC data register to an array automatically

This is not a complete list, but I am sure there is more than one example of this in the STM32 Standard Peripheral Library that you can download from here:

[STM32F0xx](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1743/PF257884#)

[STM32F10x](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1743/PF257890)

[STM32F2xx](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1743/PF257898)

You did not specify more than ARM Cortex M3 from STM32, so choose the right one above. You can also look and probably use most of the code in the examples from the other two libraries as well. When you open these zip files open the file named:

```
stm32fxxx_stdperiph_lib_um.chm
```

and press "Related pages" and then "STM32Fxxx Standard Peripherals Examples"